# onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState not restoring the listview state

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to Android app development. And was trying a small code to retain the listView data even though the screen orientation is changed.

**

- activity_main.xml

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Name"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="43dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1060=dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText"
        android:text="Add Name" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="View Names" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**

- MainActivity.java

**

```
package com.example.providerexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String tag = getClass().getSimpleName();
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    ListView listView;
   // SQLiteDatabase db;
    DataBaseHandler dbHandler;
    List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter listAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

       // db = new SQLiteDatabase();
        dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler(this);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            //Add the name to the local database
            public void onClick(View v1) {
                //dbHandler.onCreate(db);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Entering", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v(tag,"Entering Button1 onClick");
                dbHandler.addData(getApplicationContext(),editText.getText().toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v(tag,"Exiting Button1 onClick");
            }
        });

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
           //View the name from the local database
            public void onClick(View v2) {
                Log.v(tag,"Entering Button2 onClick");
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "View Name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                newList = dbHandler.getNameList();
                listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,newList);
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                Log.v(tag,"Exiting Button2 onClick");
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.v(tag,"Entering onSaveInstanceState");
        outState.putParcelable("listView.state", listView.onSaveInstanceState());
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.v(tag,"Entering onRestoreInstanceState");
        Parcelable listViewState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("listView.state");
        listView.onRestoreInstanceState(listViewState);
    }
}
```

**

- DataBaseHandler.java

**

```
package com.example.providerexample;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    String tag = getClass().getSimpleName();
    //DATABASE VERSION
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    //DATABASE NAME
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    //TABLE NAME
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Name";
    //COLUMN NAME
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "ColName";
    String NameList;

    //Constructor
    public DataBaseHandler(Context context){
        /**
         * Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database.
         * This method always returns very quickly.  The database is not actually
         * created or opened until one of {@link #getWritableDatabase} or
         * {@link #getReadableDatabase} is called.
         *
         * @param context to use for locating paths to the the database
         * @param name of the database file, or null for an in-memory database
         * @param factory to use for creating cursor objects, or null for the default
         * @param version number of the database (starting at 1); if the database is older,
         *     {@link #onUpgrade} will be used to upgrade the database; if the database is
         *     newer, {@link #onDowngrade} will be used to downgrade the database
         */
         super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.v(tag,"Exiting DataBaseHandler");
    }
    //Create Table
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        Log.v(tag,"Entering onCreate");
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        Log.v(tag,"Exiting onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        Log.v(tag,"Entering onUpgrade");
        String CONTENT = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(CONTENT);
        onCreate(db);
        Log.v(tag,"Exiting onUpgrade");
    }

    //Insert Data
    public void addData(Context context, String name){
        Log.v(tag,"Entering addData");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME,name);
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
        Log.v(tag,"Exiting addData");
    }

    //List the data
    public List<String> getNameList(){
        String selectQuery = "SELECT *FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);
        List<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                contentList.add(cursor.getString(0));
            } while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return contentList;
    }
}
```

When I change the screen orientation from portrait mode to horizontal or vice-versa, the listView data gets lost. Please help.

Comment: a suggestion: good time to start using Livedata and Room database

Comment: AFAIK onRestoreInstanceState of ListView will not restore data of ListView it just restore states like selectedPosition. You are setting list adapter inside button click when you are rotating device even adapter is not set because of that list is empty.